# How do I hide a single sheet, in google spreadsheets, using google-spreadsheet-api?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wish to be able to hide certain sheets in my Google spreadsheet programmatically. So when a shared user logs into the spreadsheet, certain data ranges, sheets maybe hidden from their view. This way I can make all, some or no spreadsheet data visible according to the viewers email address.

I have no problem doing this with sheet protection using SpreadsheetApp classes and methods, and protecting certain sheets based on the viewers email address.  But cant seem to find any classes or methods that support sheet hiding methods or properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=995&q=hide%20sheet&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) for hiding/showing sheets; you might like to star it to be kept updated.

Comment: Thanx AdamL, I have commented on the  http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=995 for hiding/showing sheets